# How to automatic load .profile in Solaris 10

Tags: unix, solaris, .profile

I have set some of my default PATH that I wanted to run in the .profile.
However the machine forget it everytime I logout and I have to reload the profile everytime by typeing source ./.profile

Is there a way to set it to startup or something similar ?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Why do you need to launch `./.profile` instead of `.profile`? Do you mean that `.` is not in your path?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `source`, you are likely using `bash` given the fact `source` is not supported by `/bin/ksh` or `/bin/sh` under Solaris.

Bash is reading `.bash_profile` when it exists and in such case, ignores `~/.profile`.

You then need to set your PATH in `.bash_profile`.